# How to construct a set of local Hamiltonians sharing the same ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, ground-state

In the quantum approximate optimization algorithms, the superposition state $|+\rangle^{\otimes N}$ is usually prepared as the initial state, which is the ground state of driven Hamiltonian $H_M=\sum_i^NX_i$. Can we find more $H_M$ that shares the same ground state $|+\rangle^{\otimes N}$?

Comment: ...trivially by adding some constant?!

Comment: @JasonFunderberker That is trivial. Is there any non-trivial solutions?

Comment: $H=-\sum_i^N X_i X_{i+1}$ is almost trivial, but maybe not completely.

Answer (score 0):

The key phrase you are looking for is "parent Hamiltonians". There is a lot of interesting work being done on them, [especially in the context of Matrix Product States (MPS)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6613), or tensor networks in general. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07827) outlines a method which should work for your case for finding more parent Hamiltonians.

But the short answer is yes, there should be more non-trivial parent Hamiltonians of  $|+\rangle^{\otimes N}$, specifically non-driven ones. For any injective MPS, a time-independent, 1D local, frustration-free, gapped parent Hamiltonian can always be constructed which has the MPS as its unique ground state ([ref](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6613)). Since it's easy to express $|+\rangle^{\otimes N}$ as a trivial (bond-dimension 1) injective MPS, then it follows that it has at least one time-independent, 1D local, frustration-free, gapped parent Hamiltonian.

Sadly though I can't find many broad theories on the uniqueness of classes of parent Hamiltonians given a particular state.